# How to find exact substring in list of substrings?

Tags: python

Say I have this dictionary:

```
lookup = {"text_text": 1, "text_text_num": 1}
```

And a list of strings:

```
my_strings = ["text_text_part1", "text_text_part2", "text_text_another_part3", "text_text_num_something_part3"]
```

How can I ensure that `my_strings[0]`, `my_strings[1]` and `my_strings[2]` are only matched with `text_text` from `lookup` while `my_strings[3]` is matched with `text_text_num`? The suffix is dynamic and I can't regex the desired part from my strings because I don't know when they stop.

Comment: Your `lookup` doesn't seem to be valid Python. Do you mean `'text_text'` instead of `text_text`?

Comment: Yes, apologies. Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `lookup`'s keys are sorted from shortest to longest (that being said, a `list` might be more appropriate as a container):

```
def find(my_strings, lookup):
  for string in my_strings: # For each string
    matched = None
    
    for word in lookup:     # Check all words
      if word in string:    # If a match is found
        matched = word      # Assign to matched, even if it already has a non-None value
    
    print(f'{string}: {matched}')
```

Try it:

```py
lookup = {
    'text_text': 1,
    'text_text_num': 1
}

my_strings = [
    'text_text_part1',
    'text_text_part2',
    'text_text_another_part3',
    'text_text_num_something_part3'
]

find(my_strings, lookup)
# text_text_part1: text_text
# text_text_part2: text_text
# text_text_another_part3: text_text
# text_text_num_something_part3: text_text_num
```

Comment: I should have clarified this in my question, but what if my list looks like this: `my_strings = ["text_text_num_something_part3"]`? And I still want to match it with  text_text_num only?

Comment: @Omega Your `my_strings` list matters not; only `lookup` needs to be sorted. That being said, even if your list look like that, this answer will still give you what you want.

Comment: The truth catches also such elements `'num_text_text_part1'`.

Comment: @СергейКох I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I don't see anything in the question forbid that.

Comment: `startswith` is better than `in` in this case.

Comment: @СергейКох It is, if the OP explicitly stated that `lookup` only contain prefixes and not just substrings. Since there is no such detail in the question, I made no assumption.